# Error on ansible-playbook on simple apache2 task

Tags: apache, ansible

Trying my hands on ansible with a small orchestration but quickly run in to issue on a simple apache issue. At the point of restarting after enabling mod_proxy, it fails with :

```
~$ ansible-playbook ansible/playbooks/apache_tomcat_mysql_mongo_stack.yml -u ansible --private-key ~/ansible/ansible.pem
PLAY [web] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [192.168.56.103]

TASK: [apache | Update apt cache]  ********************************************* 
ok: [192.168.56.103]

TASK: [apache | Install Apache2] ********************************************** 
ok: [192.168.56.103]

TASK: [apache | Creating a Document virtualhost file] ************************* 
skipping: [192.168.56.103]

TASK: [apache | Creating a Reverse Proxy virtualhost file] ******************** 
ok: [192.168.56.103]

TASK: [apache | Activate Mod Proxy] ******************************************* 
changed: [192.168.56.103]

NOTIFIED: [apache | Restart-Apache] ******************************************* 
failed: [192.168.56.103] => {"failed": true}
msg: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

NOTIFIED: [apache | Restart-Apache] ******************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

NOTIFIED: [apache | Restart-Apache] ******************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
       to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/apache_tomcat_mysql_mongo_stack.retry

192.168.56.103             : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Below is the playbook apache_tomcat_mysql_mongo_stack.yml

```
- hosts: web
  roles:
  - apache
  sudo: True
  vars:
    document_vhost: False
    proxy_vhost: True
    activate_vhost: False
    deactivate_vhost: False
    apache_domain_name: node3.localhost
    apache_admin_email_address: devops@node3.localhost
    apache_port: 80
    activate_vhost: True
    apache_vhosts:
    - apache_proxy_context: /
      reversed_server_mod: ajp
      reversed_server_ip: 192.168.56.105
      reversed_server_port: 8009
      reversed_server_context: /
- hosts: tomcat
  roles:
  - java
  - tomcat
  sudo: True
  vars:
    java_version: 7
    tomcat_version: 7
    tomcat_port: 8080
    tomcat_redirection_port: 8443
    tomcat_ajp_port: 8009
    tomcat_ajp_redirection_port: 8443
    tomcat_ajp_server_fake_name: Server
    tomcat_jvmroute_name: jvmroute1
```

All related information like apache role and handlers are found on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/10139308) for sake for brevity. I can't really figure out what's happening as it looks like ansible is trying to start a different apache service aside the one already running.

How to solve issues like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 things you could investigate further:

> msg: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down

This looks like apache can't bind TCP port 80 because something else is using it. Run `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 80` before running the playbook and verify exactly which process is listening on port 80. Make sure it's apache.

> AH00015: Unable to open logs

This looks like maybe the filesystem permissions for apache to write to it's log files might be wrong. You should also verify the relevant directory permissions for `/var/log/apache2` (or whatever the path is for your distro).

Comment: Looks like I shot myself on the leg. There was an incomplete removal of nginx that I had installed there and `netstat -ano | grep 80` that I was using could not reveal the culprit. thanks